# Can "que" be an interrogative subject pronoun?

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-interrogatifs

In the following sentence (a newspaper headline), why is "que" used and not "qui" or "qu'est-ce qui"?

> Mais que sont ces cercles rouges sur le dos de Michael Phelps?

Update: On reflection, I think it might be as simple as this: "que" is merely the interrogative pronoun; the noun phrase "ces cercles rouges" is the subject proper.

Answer (score 6):

*Qui* and *que* are both interrogative words. Interrogative words bear the indication of what kind of information you are looking for in the answer. For example, *quand* ("when") shows you are expecting information about time, *où* ("where") shows you are expecting information about place.
*Qui* is used to show you are expecting information about persons and *que* about things /ideas. **Both**, *qui* and *que* **can be subject or object** according to their function in the sentence.

> Que vois-tu ?

The answer will be a thing/things.

> Qui vois-tu ?

The answer will be a person/people.  In both cases the interrogative pronoun is object to the verb.

In the following question :

> Mais que sont ces cercles rouges sur le dos de Michael Phelps ?

*que* is the subject of *sont* and it represents things, namely *ces cercles rouges* (the red circles) visible on Michael Phelps's back, we want information on those marks, we can only use *que* here.

We could also say:

> Mais qu'est-ce que sont ces cercles rouges sur le dos de Michael Phelps ?

In the sentence:

> Qui sont ces gens assis sur le bord de la piscine ?

by using *qui* we indicate we are asking about the identity of the people.

If we said:

> Que sont ces gens assis sur le bord de la piscine ?

*que* would indicate we want to know about the function of these people (ordinary spectators? journalists ? trainers ?...)

Comment: Agreed,    Mais qu'est-ce que sont ces cercles rouges sur le dos de Michael Phelps ? does not really sound good..

Comment: @SteevenBrunner Just search *qu'est-ce que sont ces* in a search engine to see it's quite usual in French. To avoid saying Internet is in no way a reference as far as good use of language is concerned (to which I entirely agree to) here are some more literary uses: [Qu’est-ce que sont ces cartes ?](http://bit.ly/2b31t54), [Mais qu'est-ce que sont ces méthodes ?](http://bit.ly/2bmXX4t),  [Qu’est-ce que sont ces hommes qui le tiennent ?](http://bit.ly/2aLX7wv), [Qu'est-ce-que sont ces fenêtres ?](http://bit.ly/2aPQIDg), [Mais qu'est-ce que sont ces pratiques ?](http://bit.ly/2bmZvv5) etc.

Comment: After a little more study, I think I may have found the explanation.  Normally, the forms for "what" in a question are: subject = qu'est-ce qui ; direct object = que/qu'est-ce que ; after a preposition = quoi.  Hence my original question.  However, qu'est-ce que and que can also act as the subject complement/attribut du sujet with a copula verb/verbe attributif such as être, devenir, sembler etc.  I think this is what is happening in my sentence above.  And indeed, all of your examples, Laure, also contain être!

Comment: @Claudie Your example contains *être*, but I started with a different example on purpose. *Que* is indeed  an  "interrogative subject pronoun" (your question) whenever it refers to things or ideas.

Comment: @Claudie  *qu'est-ce qui...* : **qui**  is subject of the following verb, not of *être*  (*Qu'est- ce qui se passe ?*);     *qu'est-ce que*  -  *que* impossible in first occurrence - second *que* is object of the following verb, not of *être* (*Qu'est-ce que tu vois ?*).

Comment: I understand that the que is acting as the subject of the verb. However, it seems it can only do this when the verb is a copula, in this case, être.  Qu'est-ce que se passe, for example, is ungrammatical (as you demonstrate).  Que serons-nous, on the other hand, is grammatical because of the presence of être.  I was looking for the grammatical principal that allowed que to act as the subject.  I'm not sure that I understand your clarification.  What different example are you referring to?

Comment: My first two examples in my answer are : *Que vois-tu ?* / *Qui vois-tu ?*, no use of *être* there.  *Qu'est-ce qui se passe ?* and  *Que serons-nous ?* are **both** grammatical:  they both refer to things, and absolutely no relevance to *être* being there or not. You say you are looking "for the grammatical principal that allowed *que* to act as the subject." : the rule is that it depends on whether is stands for a thing/idea or for a person. Whether it is subject or object has no relevance at all.

Comment: I think we might be talking at cross purposes because we agree that qu'est-ce qui se passe and que serons-nous are both grammatical and that the qu'est-ce qui and the que both refer to a thing/idea.  However, it seems we disagree as to why.  Putting aside the issue of subject versus object, my argument is that que can only be used in this way in a predicative expression (in French un groupe (pro)nominal ou un adjectif relié au sujet de la phrase par un verbe d'état).  The relevance of être, therefore, is paramount.  Qu'est-ce que se passe doesn't work because se passer isn't a copula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43865/discussion-between-laure-and-claudie).

Comment: @Laure People here ask our opinion, as a french native speaker speaking a good french, I should give them tips of which sentences are used in everyday life in France and not sentences that were used 400 years ago but no one use them anymore..

Comment: @SteevenBrunner Which sentences are you referring to? My own two self made sentences are the ones at the beginning *Que vois-tu ? Qui vois-tu ?* Apart from that I used OP's example to explain (which by the way is a very recent news headline and not their creation...). I am a French native as well, with scores of years of practise and study, but I'm not the one to pass judgement of the (good or bad) quality of the language I use, l'll leave my peers do that. By the way OP wasn't asking for an opinion but if interrogative pronoun que can be subject, that's a fact, not an opinion.

Comment: I refer to that 'Just search qu'est-ce que sont ces in a search engine to see it's quite usual in French', it's false it doesn't sound natural / usual in French, some other peoples confirmed that here. It's way way more usual to say "Mais que sont ces méthodes" than to say "Mais qu'est ce que sont ces méthodes"

Comment: La question de la perplexité p/r à la _fonction_ est difficile, dépasse sans doute le cadre de la question, mais c'est fort intéressant, d'autres questions sont possibles... Le contenu n'a pas une vocation unique. _LBU14_ parle de l'_interrogation sur l'inconnu_ où la division qui/que peut parfois s'estomper. On dit que _qui_ est même exclu quand on traite d'un représentant non identifié d'une catégorie ou dans une coordination qui mélange humain et non-humain etc. _Que vois-je de ce côté-ci du détroit ? Des gens riches._ (Stendhal, encore). Aussi une réponse à l'usuel _à quoi penses-tu ?_..

Comment: @SteevenBrunner It might not sound "good" and "natural" to **you** but saying it's **not usual** is plainly wrong, and false information is to be corrected. You made a comment based on your own  opinion and not based on research and references.  Just follow the few (plenty more to be found) I gave ( my 1st comment) and you'll see they're all 21st century (400 years old ? Can't find one  in my examples) and since **you** were giving an opinion (not founded on fact & research) I gave you facts.

Comment: @SteevenBrunner  And lots of such questions on ordinary blogs as well, but only gave the most trustworthy since you first implied it was wrong.  Quoting you : "some other people(s)  confirmed that here. " : can't find anyone confirming what you say, they must have realised there comments were out of place.

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ Tout à fait d'accord mais dans le cas présent je pensais qu'une réponse basique s'imposait !

Comment: @SteevenBrunner  I have removed my initial comment stating the form is technically incorrect as I didn't found any formal rule supporting that idea. On the other hand, ngram is reporting  "qu'est-ce que sont" appears one hundred times less than "que sont ces" and found zero occurences of "qu'est ce que sont ces" in French books so I still believe correctors reject that form. What is sure is I would never use it. This is still only my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Que means what. 
Qui means who.
In that sentence, que refers to the red circles. 
So the translation would be "What are those red circles on...."

So qui is only used when referring to people.

Answer (score 1):

Que... Qu'est ce que... Qu'est ce qui... : **What**

> Qu'est ce que sont ces cercles rouges...(*What are those red circles...*)
>
> Qu'est ce qui a fait un suçon pareil sur le dos de... (*What made such a love bite on the back of...*)

Qui...  : **Who**

> Qui a fait ces suçons sur le dos... (*Who made those love bites on the back...)

Comment: For the record, much too big to be love bites (unless by an alien ?). Such marks are bruises left by what is called "cupping therapy".  An ancient and popular Chinese practice.